# Where I can find Marklogic configuration file in Windows

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I need to edit Marklogic config file in my local Windows environment. I want to edit the time zone option in the marklogic.conf file in order for MarkLogic to operate with a different time zone setting than the OS.

I know the location for Unix systems (**/etc/sysconfig/marklogic**), [and it is recommended to apply configurations in **/etc/marklogic.conf**](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/best-practice-editing-marklogic-server-environment-variables),  but am not able to find the location on Windows.

Please share the Windows path for the MarkLogic configuration file location or how to set MarkLogic server environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to archive.

On Windows, you will find MarkLogic typically being installed under `C:\Program Files\MarkLogic`.

The installation process has also created a Windows service pointing to the `marklogic.exe` executable for you to run as a background service. The characteristics of the service can be altered using the Services snap-in on the `Microsoft Management Console`. You can start it by simply typing `Services` on the start menu.

Let me know if you're trying to archive anything in particular.

Comment: I need to edit time zone option in marklogic.conf file, I can't find the conf file in location